# Share Image of image view with intent in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an option in my app that share image to whatsapp,facebook etc. For share image through intent, i want specific image from image view on which share button is clicked.
I have the following code that does not work.it share an empty file to whatsapp.

```
    val shareBtn = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.share_btn)
    val postImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.post_image)

    val path:String?=postImage.tag.toString()
    val file= File(path)

    shareBtn.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.type = "image"
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file))
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to store image of `ImageView` , you need to convert to `Bitmap`

```
val bitMap : Bitmap =imageview.getDrawingCache();
```

now store this image to file

```
val bos : ByteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
val  file : File =  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "your_file.jpg");
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    val fos : FileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bos.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

now create an intent by specifying type 'image/jpeg'
and setting extra stream and path of the file that is to be shared

```
val intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/your_file.jpg"));
```

And start Activity by creating chooser

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: This is necessary to save image in storage directory?Can we convert bitmap to Uri? or is there any way to get path of bitmap?

Comment: Yes, because you can not directly share the bitmap object (at application level).

Comment: You can replace `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to `ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(context)`

Answer (score 2):

**a great way for share image file ( Kotlin ) :**
first create a folder named *`xml`* in the *`res`* folder and create a new XML Resource File named *`provider_paths.xml`* and put the below code inside it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="."/>

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

now go to the *`manifests`* folder and open the *`AndroidManifest.xml`* and then put the below code inside the `<application>` tag :

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" /> // provider_paths.xml file path in this example
</provider>
```

now you put the below code in the `setOnLongClickListener` :

```
button.setOnLongClickListener {
    try {
        val file = File("pathOfFile")
        if(file.exists()) {
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.setType("image/*")
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        toast("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use wildcard MIME types with `ACTION_SEND`. It is your content. You are supposed to tell the other app what the actual MIME type of that content is.