# I have the bitmap of an ImageView and I want to get the path of it uisng MediaStore API without using .insertImage()?

Tags: android, android-studio, uri, android-imageview, scoped-storage

```
binding.btnShareOne.setOnClickListener {
        
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("image/*")
       
        val bitmapDrawable = binding.ivLayoutOne.drawable.toBitmap() 
        
        val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            contentResolver,
            bitmapDrawable,
            "tempimage",
            null
        )

        val uri = Uri.parse(path)

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"))


    }
```

This is my code. I want to get the path from the bitmap and pass it to Uri. When I run my current code it gives me " java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString " error.

I have researched a bit and I think it will be solved by scoped storage but I cannot seem to implement it.

Since .insertImage() is deprecated and also Uri is returning null, this method of mine is not working to get image from image view and share it.

Please help.

Comment: Write your image to a file, such as in `getCacheDir()` on `Context`. Then, use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` to use with `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: Can you check this one? Should I save image to file like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024250/share-image-of-image-view-with-intent-in-kotlin

Comment: The accepted answer is terrible. The other answer is somewhat better. [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.1/PdfProvider) shows writing content to a file, and then making it available using `FileProvider`. In my case, it is a PDF and using `ACTION_VIEW`, but otherwise the basics are the same.

Comment: Can you enlighten me in the getCacheDir() part please?

Comment: [`getCacheDir()` is a method on `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=en#getCacheDir()). It points to a location on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) that your app can use for storing files.

Comment: I checked out on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-create-cache and understood most of the part regarding accessing cache file from internal and external storage and I applied it. But I could not use the part of context. here is my code. http://hastebin.com/idefuvuyet.kotlin

Answer (score 0):

A bitmap object doesn't have a path.  A Bitmap object is an in memory object.  Its just raw bytes.  Even if it came from a file, that association isn't kept around.